# Using VBA to duplicate rows based on years gap

Tags: excel, vba

I have an car database (Excel) with *year_from* and *year_to* columns. I would like to duplicate the line for each year between year_from and year_to. So if a car model was produced from 2007 to 2010, there would be 4 lines. I would like the last column (K) to have the current year value (ex: 2007, 2008, 2009 and 2010)

I tried to start from a VBA script I found but I'm not there yet.

```
Sub DuplicateRowsByYear()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim startYear As Integer
    Dim endYear As Integer
    Dim newRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test")
    startYear = ws.Range("E2").Value
    endYear = ws.Range("F2").Value
    
    For i = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For newRow = startYear To endYear
            ws.Rows(i).Copy
            ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = newRow
        Next newRow
    Next i
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

How should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `startYear` and `endYear` should be assigned in For loop
- Since inserted rows can change the location of data rows, the code utilizes a loop in reverse order to account for this.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub DuplicateRowsByYear()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim startYear As Long
    Dim endYear As Long
    Dim j As Long, i As Long, iGap as Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test")
    ' Loop through data in reverse order
    For i = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        startYear = ws.Range("E" & i).Value
        endYear = ws.Range("F" & i).Value
        ' Comparing startYear vs endYear
        If endYear > startYear Then
            iGap = endYear - startYear
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            ws.Rows(i).Copy
            ws.Rows(i + 1 & ":" & i + iGap).Insert
            ' Update Col K with the current year
            For j = 0 To iGap
                ws.Cells(i + j, "K").Value = startYear + j
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. It's working. Thank you!